# Get all paths to a specific key in a deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

How do i recursively search for a specific key in a deeply nested object.

For example:

```
let myObject = {a: {k:111, d:3},  b:"2", c: { b: {k: 222}}, d: {q: {w: k: 333}}} }
let result  = findAllPaths(myObject, "k")

// result = [a.k, c.b.k, d.q.w.k]
```

The result should be a list of all paths to the key anywhere in the nested object

Comment: What did try to achieve this @IDimension . Could you please share your code?

Comment: Please share the code your have tried or your research you have done so far.

Comment: The object has a syntax error. `q.k.w` is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create recursive function to do this using `for...in` loop.

```js
let myObject = {a: {k:111, d:3},  b:"2", c: { b: {k: 222}}, d: {q: {w: {k: 333}}} }

function getAllPaths(obj, key, prev = '') {
  const result = []

  for (let k in obj) {
    let path = prev + (prev ? '.' : '') + k;

    if (k == key) {
      result.push(path)
    } else if (typeof obj[k] == 'object') {
      result.push(...getAllPaths(obj[k], key, path))
    }
  }

  return result
}

const result = getAllPaths(myObject, 'k');
console.log(result);
```