# How to form a nested json structure from keys string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have two variables: currValue and keys, which is a string of keys separated by `.` like this: `global.fontsize.bodyscale`. I want to create a nested json structure from this string. The json structure should like:

```
{
    global: {
        fontsize: {
            bodyscale: {
                value: currValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Break it apart on the dot and recursively create the nested objects? There's probably packages that already do this, however.

Comment: [similar but reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352470/get-all-paths-to-a-specific-key-in-a-deeply-nested-object) this may help, you have to do reverse of this I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight` to repeatedly wrap the initial object with parent objects, based on the keys.

```js
const currValue = 'hello';
const keys = 'global.fontsize.bodyscale';

const result = keys.split('.')
  .reduceRight((obj, key) => ({[key]: obj}), {value: currValue})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keys = 'global.fontsize.bodyscale'
const currValue = 123

const keysList = keys.split('.')

const result = {}

let current = result
for (const key of keysList.slice(0, -1)) {
  current[key] = {}
  current = current[key]
}
current[keysList.at(-1)] = currValue

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for this

```
let keys = "global.fontsize.bodyscale";
const nested_keys = keys.split(".").reverse();
let obj = "currValue"

nested_keys.forEach((key) => {
    result = {}
    result[key] = obj
    obj = result
})

console.log(obj)
```